Grafana panel refresh on variable change
is there a way to instantly refresh a panel in grafana on a particular variable change , as of now it happens only when all variables are refreshed and then panels are getting re-rendered.
in our case the entire refresh of all variables takes few secs (20-30s) -> panels re-rendering happens, but we need to instantly refresh a particular panel alone where this variable is used
above can be achieved if we use auto refresh (<5s) but catch here is its applicable for all panels not the required ones alone.
Is there a way to auto refresh only specific panel in grafana not all?

No, it is not possible as of now.
Although there is a long-lasting feature request for that at github:
Refresh interval per panel #73434
